How can I get this script to only update specific columns?
I've been working off of this script that I found on YouTube for a two-way sync. The script works with 5 columns, and while my database has 14, the "database" sheet has 15 - the column that categorises the subsheets is spliced out of the subsheets. Because of this, rather than making the whole row the ID, I've made it so only the first six columns (the category is in column G on the database sheet) make up the ID. The problem I can't work out, though, is how to get the "set values" command to paste only to the editable cells. So while Columns A-F make up the ID, I'll only be actually changing columns I-N, or even to paste with an offset. This sounds super confusing how I've typed it out, so I'll just paste the script below. (this is the actual script I've been working off, but I've changed let id here to fit the part that I need to search)
function syncNoID(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() == "Database" || r.rowStart == 1) return;
  r.clear();

  let id = src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,6).getValues().toString();
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Database");
  let dbData = db.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (let i in dbData){
    if (dbData[i].toString() === id){
      db.getRange(+i+1,r.columnStart).setValue(e.value);
      return;
    }
  }
}

I can get it to work up to
r.clear();
so it clears the data, but it doesn't set the values for anything at all.
I've tried a bunch of different additions, like adding a searchrange variable to only search those first columns and a few rudimentary attempts at an offset - this is my most recent version but it's mostly just me being angry at it and trying pretty much anything.
function syncNoID(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() == "Database" || r.rowStart == 1) return;

  let id = src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,6).getValues().toString();
  const db = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Database");
  let dbData = db.getDataRange().getValues();
  let searchrange = db.getRange(1,1,db.getLastRow,6)

  for (let i in dbData){
    if (searchrange[i].toString() === id){
      db.getRange(+i+1,r.columnStart+1).setValue(e.value);
}
}
}

I'm fairly new to coding, and really know what I do know from good old google, so if anybody has some advice, that would be so appreciated.

This appears to be the source for your example: 2-Way Sync: No Unique ID?

Have you tried changing the number of columns from 5 to 14 (let id = src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,14).getValues().toString();).

@Tedinoz This is the code I've based it off, but the problem with making all of the rows the ID is that as the source sheets (the ones that will be updating the database page) are one column less than the source then it won't match those fourteen columns, if that makes sense?

This example might not precisely meet your requirements. The intention is to share an alternative that "syncs" only specific columns.
Note: This assumes that only one cell will be edited at a time. This doesn't handle editing multiple cells simultaneously, i.e., copy-pasting various cells at once.
/**
 * Sets the how many columns to use to find a matching record (row)
 */
const COLUMNS = 5;

/**
 * Simple On Edit Trigger
 *
 * @param {EditEventObject} e
 */
function onEdit(e) {
  if(
      // Source sheet
      e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Source' 
      // Between column I and column N, inclusive
      && e.range.columnStart >= 9 && e.range.columnStart <= 14 
    ){
      /** Matching row */
      const rowStart = vlookup(e);
      if(rowStart > 0){
        /** Target range */
        const target = e.source.getSheetByName('Target').getRange(rowStart, e.range.columnStart);
        /** Set the value */
        target.setValue(e.value);
      } else {
        e.source.toast('No matching row');
      }
  }
}

/**
 * Custom "vlookup". Finds a row matching the first N column values. 
 * @param {EditEventObject} e
 * @returns {number} Matching row start
 */
function vlookup(e){
  const key = e.range.getSheet()
     .getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, COLUMNS)
     .getDisplayValues()[0];
  const values  = e.source.getSheetByName('Target')
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  return values.findIndex(
    rowContent => rowContent.slice(0, COLUMNS)
       .every((value,i) => value === key[i])
  ) + 1;
}


This looks really helpful. Is the custom vlookup then in place of that piece above or in place of the entire code? My thing with this sort of thing is that I can learn bits and pices but struggle with using them together.

@BoudiccaMorgana You can put it in the same .gs file as the onEdit simple trigger or a different .gs file from the same Google Apps Script project.

ah of course, that's on me, I definitely just wasn't paying enough attention and I got that now. So the code makes sense and it's trying to run but it keeps throwing up "no matching row", even if I copy/paste the values exactly. I've tried tinkering but it's not really coming back with anything different. Not sure you have any ideas at all?

@BoudiccaMorgana The script in this answer "listens" for edits on a sheet named Source and looks for a matching row on a Target sheet. Does your spreadsheet have sheets named Source and Target? If you made any change to your copy of the script in this answer, I suggest you post a new question that includes sample data and a detailed description of the steps followed.

yes, absolutely. So I don't have any sheets called "source" so I updated it to be that it checks if the Target sheet, called "Total", isn't selected. But I also tried it a few different ways like creating a list of source sheets so I'm not sure where it went wrong. Here's the link to the type of thing I'm looking at: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/176OpgTI9BtIn8JcgzCJs-2fIVG7TDPdnMQpUu_1G23g/edit?usp=sharing

@BoudiccaMorgana Start by creating a [mcve]. The linked spreadsheet has too many sheets, and the Google Apps Script project contains many .gs files.

omg you are absolutely right I shared the wrong link. Here's the right one, that is totally on me. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JytTQotfsq-Zoc2vRd2QmHGaYk5jr9GTvPIFlr8Snk4/edit?usp=sharing
